# database is catching wrong result from javascript

Tags: javascript

can anyone help me please? So I'm making a web app where a user can crack the vault code by clicking the numbers from 1-40. They are only allowed to click 6 sets of numbers for example "6", "20", "1", "40", "27", "15". So I have a data variable "guess" in my database with int(12) as the var numbers in this JS below. The problem is whenever I try "40", "39", "38", "37", "36", "35". The database will catch "2147483647" and I'm getting confused why, there must be something wrong in what I'm doing. I'm not really professional with JS and I'm just following some guides. This was working when I had the 0-9 numbers in the vault and int(6) in the data var "guess" inside the database. Please help, thank you!

```
var numbers     = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
var screenSpans = document.querySelectorAll('#screen span');
var clear       = document.getElementById('clear');
var enter       = document.getElementById('enter');
var errorModal  = document.getElementById('digitAmountAlert');
var currEmail   = document.getElementById('currEmail').innerHTML.replace(/\s/g, '');
var lastModal   = document.getElementById('lastModal');
var main        = document.getElementById('main');
var guess       = '';
var reset;

clear.addEventListener('click', function(){
reset = 0;
for (var i = screenSpans.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (screenSpans[i].innerHTML != '' && reset == 0){
        screenSpans[i].innerHTML = '';
        reset = 1;
    }
};
});

enter.addEventListener('click', function(){
reset = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < screenSpans.length; i++) {

    // Catch if they have not entered enough digits
    if (screenSpans[i].innerHTML == ''){
        errorModal.className = 'modal';
        setTimeout(function(){
            errorModal.className = 'modal hide';
        }, 4000);

    } else {
        guess = guess+screenSpans[i].innerHTML;
        if (guess.length == 12){
            $.ajax({
                  url: "submit.php",
                  method: "POST",
                  data: { guess: guess, email: currEmail }
            });

            lastModal.className = 'modal';
            main.className = 'hide';
        }
    }
};
guess = '';
});

for (var i = numbers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
numbers[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    reset = 0;
    nextSpan(this.innerHTML);
});
};

function nextSpan (currNumber){
for (var i = 0; i < screenSpans.length; i++) {
    if (screenSpans[i].innerHTML == '' && reset == 0){
        screenSpans[i].innerHTML = currNumber;
        reset = 1;
    }
};
}

/*
|---------------------------------------------------
| FORM SUBMIT CHECK
|---------------------------------------------------
*/

var submitButton = document.getElementById('startButton');
var form = document.getElementById('form');
var goAhead = true;

submitButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
var i, j, q = [];
for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
    if (form.elements[i].nodeName == "INPUT"){
        q.push(form.elements[i].name + "=" +     encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].value));
        var inputValue = encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].value)
        if ((inputValue == '' || inputValue == null) && (form.elements[i].name != 'online')){
            // NOT COMPLETE
            goAhead = false;
            console.log(form.elements[i].name)
        }
    }
}

if (goAhead){
    // SUBMIT
    document.getElementById('form').submit();
} else {
    this.innerHTML = "Please fill out all the fields & try again";
    setTimeout(function(){
        submitButton.innerHTML = "Let's Play!";
    }, 7000);
    goAhead = true;
}
});
```

Comment: `2147483647` is the max value for a 32bit int. I am guessing that your `guess` concatenation is creating a "number" like `403938373635` (`'40' + '39' + '38' ...`) which is overflowing. That said,  I don't really understand what you're trying to do with this code, but you almost certainly want an array of numbers instead.

Comment: <div id="numberPad">
                    <div id="screen">
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                        <section>
                        <button class="number">1</button>
                        <button class="number">2</button>
                        <button class="number">3</button>.....
                        </section>
</div>

^my html

Comment: Your `submit.php` code is more important to know.

Comment: thanks jack! it's working now, I've changed my sql info in phpMyAdmin. updated the "guess" variable from INT to BIGINT. Thank you!

Comment: All good now Jack! Thank you so much! I appreciate it! :) really made my day! Have a good one bro!